# Can I modify a JSON tree using the Domino10 NotesJson objects?

Tags: json, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I'm currently testing the new Domino 10.0.1 NOTESJSON* objects in LotusScript to see whether I could use them replace the currently used [openNTF JSON LS Classes](https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/JSON%20LotusScript%20Classes).

Since there's hardly any documentation (yet?) I'm kind of feeling my way around in the dark.

Here's a simplified version of my JSON tree:

```
[{
        "unid": "9534A90AC433D729C1258384003350B5",
        "description": "just kidding",
        "content": [{
                "unid": "ABAE2585498B4E05C125832F0046701B",
                "company": "edcom"
            }, {
                "unid": "6C5F751CE39BF1B6C125832F0046701C",
                "company": "ibm"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Purpose would be to localize any "content" object with an element `"company":"ibm"`, then change this to `"company":"hcl"`.

Problem is: I apparently can only read element values (in LotusScript debugger I see that I have the right element with the right value and type). Unfortunately LotusScript editor isn't offering my any method to change values, so I tried this:

```
Set nJsElem = vItems.GetElementByName("company")
If(nJsElem.Value = "ibm") Then
    nJsElem.Value = "hcl"
End If
```

At least the debugger isn't showing any change after this.

Let alone that I don't have any idea how I could create a new JSON string from that modification.

Question: is this not possible (yet?), or am I looking at the wrong end of the line?

Comment: My understanding is 10.0.1 includes a `NotesJSONNavigator` class and some supporting classes for parsing JSON only.  There is no "JSON builder" class yet -- although that is in the backlog.  After I've confirmed, I will post a definitive answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed. You can use the [NotesJSONNavigator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_10.0.1/basic/H_NOTESJSONNAVIGATOR_CLASS.html) class to parse JSON input. As of 10.0.1, there is no LotusScript support for building, modifying, serializing JSON.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. So I'll be sticking with the openNTF solution for a while